# What is the exact meaning of 奻?

Tags: translation

Today i saw the expression: "奻" and "女女女" are they connected is some way?

And what they mean exactly?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide context? Also, I think you meant 姦, not 奻.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, What do you mean you say "女女女"? Just as a string like that, or is it 3 女 combined to form the character `姦 (Jiān) : fornicate/rape`? Could you possibly share the expression you encountered?

---

Anyway,

[新华字典](http://zidian.911cha.com/MTBqYQ==.html) gives:

`奻 (nuán)` =

> 争吵 (Zhēngchǎo): Quarrel
>
> or
>
> 愚 (Yú): Ignorance

I'll need an answer to the first part (what is "女女女") before I can say if they're connected or not.

Comment: i don't really know... can you tell me the 2 options?